# How to use Alamofire with an array in a Json dictionary?

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, alamofire

To perform a POST request with Alamofire, I would like to create a Json dictionary with an array (with elements of type AnyObject) as a dictionary value.

However, when I define the dictionary as `[String: AnyObject]` and try to save an array it results in a `SwiftDeferredNSArray`.

```
var fields = [String: AnyObject]()
fields["key1"] = [1,2,3] // But this could also be an array of type Array<AnyObject>
fields["key2"] = "Foo"
print(fields)
```

Output: `"["key1": <_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x7fdfe9f0c2d0>(\n1,\n2,\n3\n)\n, "key2": Foo]\n"`

When the dictionary values are defined of type `Any` the output is what I expect to be:

```
var fields = [String: Any]()
fields["key1"] = [1,2,3]
fields["key2"] = "Foo"
print(fields)
```

Output: `"["key1": [1, 2, 3], "key2": "Foo"]\n"`

Unfortunately, Alamofire seems not to accept dictionary values of type `Any`:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]?' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'
```

How should I use Alamofire with POST requests with Swift arrays?

Comment: Try to declare fields dictionary like this `var fields = [String: [Int]]()`

Comment: Yes, but I would like to use it in a generic method which accept any type, including  arrays. So, it is not possible to define the type in advance...

Comment: do you get any error while passing former  dictionary?

Comment: There is no reason why that shouldn't work, but in my case the arrays will be of type `Array<AnyObject>` and shouldn't preferably be downcasted due to the many different value types in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know whether the `SwiftDeferredNSArray` output is a bug in Swift, in Swift 3 the dictionary value must be `Any` by default.

Since this is also updated in the Swift 3 version of Alamofire, the `SwiftDeferredNSArray` does not occur anymore and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem in Swift 2.2

I tried to convert the dictionary of type [String: AnyObject] to a dictionary of [NSObject: AnyObject] and then while passing the value to Alamofire converted the dictionary back to [String: AnyObject]. This worked for me. Try this solution.

Edit:

To answer your question, try

`var fields = [NSObject: AnyObject]()`